# Node.js HTTP Get Request to Mailchimp Returns Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mailchimp-api-v3.0

Whenever I run the following curl code, my request to the Mailchimp 3.0 API goes through just fine:

```
curl --request GET \
--url 'https://us12.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/' \
--user 'anystring:APIKEY'
```

However, whenever I make a request to the API using Node.js, I receive the following error:

```
Got error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80
```

I'm assuming I'm missing something or have something mismatched within my .js file, any ideas as to what that might be? Node code is below:

```
 "use strict";
/* globals require, console */
var http = require('http');


var options = {
    url: 'https://us12.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'anystring:APIKEY',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }
};

http.get(options, (res) => {
  console.log(`Got response: ${res.statusCode}`);
  // consume response body
  res.resume();
}).on('error', (e) => {
  console.log(`Got error: ${e.message}`);
});
```

EDIT: Using uncaught exception returns the following:

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:856:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:879:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1053:14)
```

EDIT 2: Fixed part of it. Was using `url` as one of my options instead of `host`. Here is the correct code for that portion:

```
var options = {
    host: 'https://us12.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'anystring:APIKEY',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }
};
```

Now I'm receiving the traceback `Got response: 400` instead of the data I'm looking to pull.

Comment: try this and tell what the console displays `.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
    console.log(err);
});`

Comment: that is a weird traceback. you are making a request to    'https://us12.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/' but you get a response saying that the connection to local environment failed..are you proxying? you need to check the webserver config how that is set up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright I seem to have it working, a few things needed to be changed:

1. As @I-Am-Not-Legend mentioned, the host and path options both needed to be set correctly.
2. The `anystring` string needed to be changed to `apikey`

Once I did these two things, the request worked as expected. Full code is below, just make sure to switch out `APIKEY` with your actual API key, and switch out `us12` with your account's corresponding datacenter (found at the end of your API key).

```
"use strict";
/* globals require, console */
var http = require('http');


var options = {
    host: 'us12.api.mailchimp.com',
    path: '/3.0/',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'apikey APIKEY',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }
};

http.get(options, (res) => {
  console.log(`Got response: ${res.statusCode}`);
  res.on('data', (chunk) => {
    console.log(`BODY: ${chunk}`);
  });
  // consume response body
  res.resume();
}).on('uncaughtException', function (err) { console.log(err); });
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback) there is no url property in options.
You are supposed to specify a host, and a path.

Your options object should look as follows.

```
var options = {
host: 'https://us12.api.mailchimp.com',
path : '/3.0/'
headers: {
    'Authorization': 'anystring:APIKEY',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
};
```